# ImageView frame doesn't fit the real size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've created an imageView in the storyBoard and created some constraints on it. Then I use a function to add a border in that imageView:

```
CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (imageView.frame.size.width), (imageView.frame.size.height));
//Make some changes in the border
[borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];
[imageView.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
```

The thing is when I run the app the border is smaller than the image. I suppose it has to be with the scale or something but I can figure it out.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show the code that is making "some changes in the border"? And, image-caps of what the result looks like, and how you *want* the result to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about manipulating the image view's layer's boarder properties directly?

```
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 7.0;
```

Comment: Fixed the problem, I was complicating it. Thanks!